# State changes in reactjs?

Tags: html, reactjs

I have following layout:-

[image]

So basically there is a banner on top and banner contains image, title and sub-title.

Next to banner there is categories bar on left, feeds in center and right navbar on the right.

Following is my current route:-

```
ReactDOM.render((
     <Router history={browserHistory}>
      <Route path="/" component={app}>
       <IndexRoute component={home}/>
       <Route path="/articles" component={articles} />
       <Route path="/articles/topics/:featureName" component={articleFeatures} />
       <Route path="/articles/:slug" component={articleContent}/>
       <Route path="interviews" component={interviews}>
          <Route path="interviews/:slug" component={interviewContent} />
       </Route>
       <Route path="collections" component={collections}>
          <Route path="collections/:slug" component={collection} />
       </Route>
  </Route>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('app'));
```

Following is my app.js :-

```
class App extends React.Component{
   render(){
     return(
       <div className="insights">
          <Banner />
          <div className="content-container">
            <LeftNavBar/>
            <div className ="feeds">{this.props.children}</div>
            <RightNavbar/>
          </div>
      </div>
   )
 }
}

export default App;
```

So, as seen from above i have put Banner, LeftNavbar and RightNavBar components in App.jsx , so there components would stay same for childrens.

Now i want to change the contents of banner component i.e banner title,banner image and banner sub title  for each page.

So my /articles/ would have different banner content and /articles/:slug would have different banner content.

So basically how do change the contents of banner component for different pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [named components](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#named-components) feature of `react-router`.

For example you change the `component` prop to `components` and then set an object containing the named components:

```
import BannerA from './BannerA';
import BannerB from './BannerB';

ReactDOM.render((
     <Router history={browserHistory}>
      <Route path="/" component={app}>
       <IndexRoute components={{ main: home, banner: BannerA }}/>
       <Route path="/articles" components={{ main: articles, banner: BannerB } } />
       <Route path="/articles/topics/:featureName" components={{ main: articleFeatures, banner: BannerA }} />
       <Route path="/articles/:slug" components={{ main: articleContent, banner: BannerA }}/>
       <Route path="interviews" component={interviews}>
          <Route path="interviews/:slug" component={interviewContent} />
       </Route>
       <Route path="collections" component={collections}>
          <Route path="collections/:slug" component={collection} />
       </Route>
  </Route>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('app'));
```

You will notice I specifically didn't add this change for all your routes, illustrating that you can still mix and match.

And then change your App to the following.  I have set a default banner in case the router doesn't provide one, and if the `main` component isn't provided we fall back on the old `this.props.children` approach.

```
 import DefaultBanner from './DefaultBanner';  

 class App extends React.Component{
   render(){
     return(
       <div className="insights">
          {this.props.banner || <DefaultBanner /> }
          <div className="content-container">
            <LeftNavBar/>
            <div className ="feeds">
              {this.props.main || this.props.children}
            </div>
            <RightNavbar/>
          </div>
      </div>
   )
 }
}
```

Comment: Then banner wont be at at the top with this as left navbar and right navbar are already there in the index.js?

Comment: I am not sure I am understanding what you asking for in this comment.  Could you please describe further?

Comment: i think i got that, but i have a query, so basically you are setting banner content from 'Banner A' or 'Banner B' right? So now these banner components have fixed content right(background image, title, description) but when i come to /articles/:slug i need to call the backend api and get the banner data from there. So how am I suppose to achieve that?

Comment: So when i reach articles/:slug I call api based on article-id which returns banner content too. So getting little confused on get that data on banner component?

Comment: Hmmm, oki I see your point in regards to the `/articles/:slug`.  You may need to make Banner a container component which connects to the router data.  Perhaps you could pass a specific <ArticleBanner /> to the articles page.  And then fish the article id out of the routing data that gets passed to it.

Comment: so should i put banner in child components on individual pages along with right navbar and left navbar? that should do i i feel. what say?